# Close an activity from different activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have activity A, activity B, Activity C. I go from A to B, b shows a login page..once user logs in i close activity b and activity a..and go to activity c. How do i get this done? I use a global variable and keep activity A in memory, so when user logs in ... i call the following:

finish();
Global variabrel acitivyt a.finish()

Where is the problem now? assume my app is running on low memory, i go to background and return back to my app. suddenly global variable is lost, so whats the solution?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is that you start activity B for result [StartActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) and when you decide to go to C you set the activity B result and finish it, when you do so, Activity A's [OnActivityResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29) method gets called with the result you've set, that way you can finish A.

example code:

Activity A

```
private static final int ACTIVITY_B_CODE = 200;
private void startB(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.clasS);
    startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_B_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if (requestCode == ACTIVITY_B_CODE){
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Activity B:

```
private void startC(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityC.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    setResult(RESULT_OK);
    finish();
 }
```

more about it: [android documentations](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Comment: doesnt differ from saving it statically. say i opened acti vity a , went to b then went to c... i went to backgroun, android os due to low memory killed my activities. when i return to c..and click on login, it fails to close activity b or a. it doesnt differ much from using global variable

Comment: if you don't use flags to change the default behavior of android stack, then the system should maintain your activities stack and thus you can actually move back from b to a even if the system killed the process.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to clear the previous activity stack once you log in and go to C.

That way, C is the new top of the Activity stack and activities A and B are removed.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityC.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

---

**EDIT:**

Another approach that I personally follow in my own apps *(might sound a little complicated, but works)*:

Launch B from A using a particular RequestCode.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, LOGIN_INTENT);
```

Login the user in Activity B. On successful login, set ResultCode in B and finish() B.

```
    onSuccessfulLoginCallback() {
         Intent resIntent = new Intent();
         setResult(LOGIN_OK, resIntent);
         finish();
}
```

The control now goes back to Activity A. Now, in onActivityResult() of A, check for the RequestCode and ResponseCode. If they match, then start Activity C and finish A.

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == LOGIN_INTENT) {
            if(resultCode == LOGIN_OK){
            Intent homeIntent = new Intent(ActivityA.this,  ActivityC.class);
            startActivity(homeIntent);
            finish();
}
```

Comment: this one not working, on click of back..i still see activity b and c

Comment: Oh, in that case, you might want to have a go at `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);`

Comment: This idea is good, but unfortunately the code you've provided doesn't do that. Whan you launch `ActivityC` with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` this **would** clear the activity stack **back to activity C**. However, since activity C **isn't already in the activity stack, it simply launches activity C on top of the other activities in the stack**. Adding `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASKFLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` won't help either. Sorry.

Comment: @DavidWasser : Sir, thank you for pointing that out. In my haste, I seemed to have missed that crucial point. Anyway, I have updated my answer with a solution that I use personally. Have a look at it, if you may, and maybe reconsider that downvote. :)

Comment: @user3278732 : Try the updated solution. Let me know if anything is not clear.

Comment: If think you should delete this answer, as the content and the comments would be confusing to someone looking at it. Then create a new answer with your new content.

Comment: Just realised that the updated answer and the other answer on the page are basically talking about the same thing. :/